# Removing embedded features from a PDF in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf

I'm looking for a way to remove embedded features from a PDF document. I recently purchased a Kindle DX. When I try to open some of my PDF files on the device, I get a message saying:

> this pdf cannot be opened due to embedded features not yet supported
>   by kindle

I'm looking for a way to remove the use of these features from the document so I can view it on my Kindle. I'm a Ubuntu Linux user. (I tried opening the PDF in Document Viewer and printing it to a PDF file by going to File->Print. This make it so I could open it on the Kindle DX, but the font is messed up and very difficult to read. This won't do.)

Comment: Can you post a sample PDF? I'd like to know what kind of "embedded features" the Kindle might be talking about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/removing-password-from-pdf-on-linux/

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: Mark didn't mention the problem was password-protection on his PDFs.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The embedded files still there.

Answer (score 5):

@barbaz's brief answer worked for me. Here are the details on how I achieved success:

I downloaded qpdf-2.2.4-bin-mingw.zip from the SourceForge site and extracted the main folder in the zip to `c:\qpdf` on my Windows 7 box. I opened a Command Prompt in the `bin` directory and ran:

```
qpdf --decrypt infile.pdf outfile.pdf
```

My infile.pdf was over 4MB, full of fancy formatting and images. The document security properties displayed 'password security', not for opening but for changing, commenting, extracting. The document would not open on my standard Kindle.

The new outfile.pdf opened up in Acrobat and looks the same. The document security properties displays 'No Security', and more importantly, the new PDF opens on my Kindle after attaching the USB cable and copying the PDF to the Kindle's `document` directory.

Answer (score 2):

To my experience you cannot remove restrictions with pdftk unless you know the password for the file.

```
qpdf --decrypt
```

should however be able to remove print/edit/copy-type restrictions.

Comment: Mark didn't mention the problem was password-protection on his PDFs.

Comment: @pipitas Right, indeeed he doesn't want to remove restrictions but features. I was inspired by the URL of the 'High Tech Man' post :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this Ghostscript commandline:

```
gs \
 -o kindle-ready.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
  input.pdf
```